# How can class name be used as data type?

Tags: java

```
public class node {

    int data;
    node next;

    node(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This is a class that I saw online for a linked list.
I am not sure how it used node next.

For example, int `data` is creating variable data with type `int`.
But then `node next` is creating a variable named next with type node? But I thought there is no such type as a node.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you understand that every class is a type?

Comment: So, every class can be used as a type?

Comment: Yes.  Every class >>is<< a type, so therefore it can be >>used<< as a type.

Comment: I hope that you can read a simple java book. The answers to this question should be in the first couple chapters.

Answer (score 9):

This will be a little bit clearer if we use correct style:

```
public class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node (int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

`Node` is a class.  Each `Node` instance has a field (`data`) to hold an integer value, and a field (`next`) to hold a reference to another `Node` instance.

(As noted in the comments, all Java classes are types, so `Node next;` is declaring a field whose name is `next` and whose type is `Node`.  Furthermore, every `Node` instance will have one of these fields ... that can refer to another `Node` instance.)

So, to create a linked list from `Node` instances, you link one `Node` to the next one in the list using (naturally) the `next` field.  The last `Node` in the list (typically) has a `null` in its `next` field.

---

> But I thought there is no such type as a node.

Every Java class is a type, and we just defined `node` (or more correctly `Node`) as a Java class.

> So, it is just creating a new object called `next`. Am I right?

Not exactly.  You would be creating an object (a `Node` instance) and assigning the object's *reference* to the `next` field of some other `Node` instance.

The object is not called `next`.  It is the field that is called `next`.  And the field contains a *reference to an object* rather than an object itself.

(These small distinctions in the terminology are actually important to understanding what is really going on.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have been spending all day learning about the basics of Java. I did not understand some of your answers. Now, I am feeling better. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're mixing up Primitive types with Reference types. It's important going forward to always differentiate between the two. It seems like you're just starting out so you probably were first introduced to Primitive types like int, double, char and so on. Well reference types are ones that we define with the `class` keyword. When you are making a class you can think of it as also making a new type. So you can think of the node class in your example as creating a type `node`.

Comment: Yes, I am new to programming. So, it is just creating a new object called next. Am I right? Thank you

Comment: No, you are creating a reference called next. Next can refer to any Node object that you create and assign to next. However, until you assign the value of next, it is null.